# How to find out which sms has not been delivered or sent?

Tags: java, android, sms, report, message

I have following code and I want to know which sms has been delivered or not.
My code sends 1-5 sms every 30 seconds, so when toast "sms not delivered" appears, I do not know which one was not delivered. I don't know if this is the right way to do this but It was the most common solution to this problem

```
public boolean sendSMS(String id, String num, String msg) {
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
            SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    registerReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    registerReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReciever, new 
 IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage("xxxxxxxx", null, msg, sentPI, deliveredPI);

    Log.e("Message Sent", num + "  " + msg + "  " + id);

    return true;
}


class DeliverReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {


        switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "sms delivered",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "sms not delivered",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }

    }
}

class SentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "sms sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }

    }
```

I'm sorry for my bad English.

EDIT:

```
 public boolean sendSMS(String id, String num, String msg) {
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
            SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    registerReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    registerReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReciever, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

    smsManager.sendTextMessage("+xxxxxxxxxx", null, msg, sentPI, deliveredPI);

    Log.e("Message Sent", num + "  " + msg + "  " + id);

    return true;
}


public class DeliverReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if (bundle != null){
                final Object[] bObject = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < bObject.length; i++){

                    SmsMessage current = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) bObject[i]);
                    String phoneNum = current.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Deliver Reciever",e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Debug screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t71FU.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, make your SmSManager a static class object.  Then you can get the current phone number/phone numbers from the PDU that is hiddent inside intent object.

```
final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String phone = "";
    SmsMessage smsMessage;

    try {

        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdu = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdu");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdu.length; i++) {

                 smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdu[i]);
                 phone = current.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is another problem. When i try to get PDUs, it throws NullPointerException because Object is null. Why is this happening? PS. Thanks for help

Comment: Can you append your original code with the modifications you made?

Comment: Also can you put a breakpoint on that line and post what the bundle object has at that point?

Comment: I edited the post. There is a new code and debug screenshot.

Comment: I can't see everything inside bundle but from what I am seeing just remove the "s".  (Object[]) bundle.get("pdu") should do it

Comment: I figured it out few minutes ago.  And can I ask? Is it possible to have some message ID? For example. I've sended sms 10 times to one number and I want to know which one was not delivered or sent. PS. I have created Smsmessage from pdu. Thank you !

Comment: current.getProtocolIdentifier() will return a unique ID I believe.  However if you are logging this information I would do something like LOG.info("ID: " + current.getProtocolIdentifier() + " Phoner: " + current.getDisplayOriginatingAddress() + "Message: " + current.getDisplayMessageBody()); that should be enough to uniquely identify a message.  Because if you just store it by unique ID you still won't really know exactly whcih one failed and which one sent from a practical standpoint.  Enjoy and best of luck to you